# Homomorphism and irreducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let R[x] be a polynomial ring. Let S[x] be another polynomial ring such that $R[x]\subset S[x]$ . Let $\phi: R[x]\rightarrow S[x]$ be an inclusion homomorphism.
Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $R[x]$ and $g(x)\in S[x]$ be the polynomial obtained after applying the homomorphism.

If $g(x)$ is irreducible in $S[x]$, what can we be inferred of $f(x)$?
Is $f(x)$ irreducible?

Also 2)I arrived at a condition that,  $\phi: R[x]\rightarrow R[x]$, be such that,  $g(x)=\phi(f(x))$ is irreducible. Does it mean $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Thank you for any hint or help.

Comment: Is $ \phi $ the inclusion map? If not, I don't see how $ R[x] \subseteq S[x] $ is relevant.

Comment: Yes $\phi$ is an inclusion homomorphism, I have corrected it

Comment: If $f=f_1f_2$ where $\deg(f_1),\deg(f_2)>0$ and $\phi$ is the inclusion homomorphism, then $g=\phi(f)=\phi(f_1)\phi(f_2)$ where $\deg\phi(f_1),\deg\phi(f_2)>0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ R = \mathbb{Z} $, $ S = \{\frac{a}{2^n} : a \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 0\} $, i.e. localization by the powers of 2, and $ \phi $ be the inclusion map. Then $ 6 \in R $ is reducible, but $ 6 \in S $ is irreducible, as in $ S $, 2 is a unit and 3 is irreducible. Then the same counterexample works for $ R[x] $ and $ S[x] $.